# CLR sequential structs layout: aligning and size

Tags: c#, .net, struct, clr, value-type

All `struct`s in C# by default are treated as `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]`-marked value types. So lets take some number of `struct`s and inspect sizes of this `struct`s:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class Foo
{
  struct E { }
  struct S0 { byte a; }
  struct S1 { byte a; byte b; }
  struct S2 { byte a; byte b; byte c; }
  struct S3 { byte a; int b; }
  struct S4 { int a; byte b; }
  struct S5 { byte a; byte b; int c; }
  struct S6 { byte a; int b; byte c; }
  struct S7 { int a; byte b; int c; }
  struct S8 { byte a; short b; int c; }
  struct S9 { short a; byte b; int c; }
  struct S10 { long a; byte b; }
  struct S11 { byte a; long b; }
  struct S12 { byte a; byte b; short c; short d; long e; }
  struct S13 { E a; E b; }
  struct S14 { E a; E b; int c; }
  struct S15 { byte a; byte b; byte c; byte d; byte e; }
  struct S16 { S15 b; byte c; }
  struct S17 { long a; S15 b; }
  struct S18 { long a; S15 b; S15 c; }
  struct S19 { long a; S15 b; S15 c; E d; short e; }
  struct S20 { long a; S15 b; S15 c; short d; E e; }

  static void Main()
  {
    Console.WriteLine("name: contents => size\n");
    foreach (var type in typeof(Foo).GetNestedTypes(BindingFlags.NonPublic))
    {
      var fields = type.GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
      Console.WriteLine("{0}: {2} => {1}", type.Name, Marshal.SizeOf(type),
        string.Join("+", fields.Select(_ => Marshal.SizeOf(_.FieldType))));
    }
  }
}
```

Output is (the same on x86/x64):

```
name: contents => size

E:  => 1
S0: 1 => 1
S1: 1+1 => 2
S2: 1+1+1 => 3
S3: 1+4 => 8
S4: 4+1 => 8
S5: 1+1+4 => 8
S6: 1+4+1 => 12
S7: 4+1+4 => 12
S8: 1+2+4 => 8
S9: 2+1+4 => 8
S10: 8+1 => 16
S11: 1+8 => 16
S12: 1+1+2+2+8 => 16
S13: 1+1 => 2
S14: 1+1+4 => 8
S15: 1+1+1+1+1 => 5
S16: 5+1 => 6
S17: 8+5 => 16
S18: 8+5+5 => 24
S19: 8+5+5+1+2 => 24
S20: 8+5+5+2+1 => 24
```

Looking at this results I can't understand the layout (fields aligning and total size) ruleset CLR used for sequential structs. Can somebody explain me this behavior?

Comment: Are you asking for the ruleset used by the CLR for structs in managed space (which is an implementation detail) or the ruleset used by the marshaller when marshalling structs between managed an unmanaged space (Marshal.SizeOf returns the size of a struct after marshalling, not of the struct in managed space)?

Comment: Narrow it down a bit, which particular results are unexpected?

Comment: @dtb with sequential layout this two things are completely the same. `Marshal.SizeOf()` gives completely the same sizes, as C# `sizeof` operator returns.

Comment: @ControlFlow: They're not necessarily the same: For example, a CLR `bool` takes up one byte; a marshalled `bool` requires 4 bytes.

Comment: @ControlFlow: another example: a CLR `char` takes up two bytes; `Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(char))` returns 1.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All the fields are aligned depending on their type.  The native types (`int`, `byte`, etc.) are all aligned by their size.  For example, an `int` will always be at a multiple of 4 bytes in, while a byte can be anywhere.

If smaller fields come before an `int`, padding will be added if necessary to ensure the `int` is properly aligned to 4 bytes.  This is why `S5` (1+1+4 = 8) and `S8` (1+2+4 = 8) will have padding and end up the same size:

```
[1][1][ ][ ][4] // S5
[1][ ][ 2  ][4] // S8
```

Additionally, the struct itself inherits the alignment of its most-aligned field (ie. for `S5` and `S8`, `int` is the most-aligned field, so both of them have an alignment of 4).  Alignment is inherited like this so that when you have an array of structs, all the fields in all the structs will be properly aligned.  So, 4+2 = 8.

```
[4][2][ ][ ] // starts at 0
[4][2][ ][ ] // starts at 8
[4][2][ ][ ] // starts at 16
```

Notice the 4 is always aligned by 4. Without inheriting from the most-aligned field, every other element in an array would have its `int` aligned by 6 bytes instead of 4:

```
[4][2] // starts at 0
[4][2] // starts at 6 -- the [4] is not properly aligned!
[4][2] // starts at 12
```

This would be very bad because not all architectures allow reading from unaligned memory addresses, and even the ones that do have a (potentially quite large, if on a cache line or page boundary) performance penalty for doing it.

Beyond basic performance, alignment also comes into play with concurrency. The C# memory model guarantees reads/writes of the native types up to 4 bytes wide are atomic, and .NET has atomic features like the `Interlocked` class. Atomic operations like these boil down to CPU instructions that themselves require aligned memory access to work.

Proper alignment is very important!

You will often see clever native coders keep all of this in mind while laying out their structures, sorting all fields from largest to smallest in an effort to keep padding, and thus struct size, to a minimum.

Comment: Thany you! But what about fields of non-native types?

Comment: If struct inherits alignment from the most-aligned field, why `struct S22 { S16 a; S15 b; }` produces `6 + 5 => 11` output? most-aligned field is `a` of size `6`, isn't it?

Comment: non-native types inherit the alignment of their most-aligned field.  So `S15` is aligned by `1`, because its most-aligned field is of type `byte`. `S16` is also aligned by `1`, because it only contains a `S15` and `byte`.

Comment: Another reason for alignment is because of multithreading. Generally speaking* a misaligned int is not guaranteed to be updated in a single atomic operation on x86 or most other platforms. That means if Thread A writes a new value to int X at the same time Thread B is reading int X, Thread B might get a mangled value made up of half the bits of the old value and half the bits of the new value. Correctly aligned 16/32/64bit values are written in a single atomic operation (8bit values are always 'correctly aligned').