# Invalid struct size in C#

Tags: c#

I have the following C# struct:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal struct MY_STRUCT
{
     public uint A;
     public IntPtr B;
     public uint C;
}
```

I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 64-bit platform the size of `uint` in which is **4** bytes and the size of `IntPtr` is **8** bytes.

Then, why when i call `Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MY_STRUCT))` i get 24 instead of 16??? Any help please.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/8264681/209199

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will need to set the [Pack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.pack%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of the StructLayout attribute.

I suppose the default is platform dependent and equal to 8 on x64. To get 16 bytes:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=4)]
internal struct MY_STRUCT
{
     public uint A;
     public IntPtr B;
     public uint C;
}
```